# Seleccionar ultimos 50 meses sql pgadmin

Tags: sql, date, pgadmin

Muestre toda la información de los pedidos cuyo tipo no comience por la letra a, que hayan
sido realizados por clientes mayores de 35 años, que tengan algún crédito cuyo valor sea
mayor a 2000, y que hayan ganado algún premio en los últimos 50 meses, con alguna tarjeta
cuyo nombre tenga menos de 10 caracteres, muestre además el nombre del cliente y la
fecha en la que ganó el premio.

```
select distinct pedidos, cliente.nombre_cli as "nombre", 
premios.fecha_premio as "fecha del premio"
from pedidos,cliente,credito,premios,tarjeta_premios
where cliente.cod_cli = pedidos.cod_cli
and cliente.cod_cli = credito.cod_cli
and cliente.cod_cli = premios.cod_cli
and premios.cod_tarj = tarjeta_premios.cod_tarjeta
and pedidos.tipo not like 'a%'
and (current_date-cliente.fecha_nac_cli)/365.25>35
and credito.valor>2000
and length(tarjeta_premios.nombre)<10
and current_date-(premios.fecha_premio/50) >
```

;

Como podria seleccionar los ultimos 50 meses ?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! la fecha tiene que se mayor a la fecha actual menos 50 meses... eso no lo sabes hacer?

Comment: Pon el código como texto.

Comment: select distinct pedidos, cliente.nombre_cli as "nombre", premios.fecha_premio as "fecha del premio"
from pedidos,cliente,credito,premios,tarjeta_premios
where cliente.cod_cli = pedidos.cod_cli
and cliente.cod_cli = credito.cod_cli
and cliente.cod_cli = premios.cod_cli
and premios.cod_tarj = tarjeta_premios.cod_tarjeta
and pedidos.tipo not like 'a%'
and (current_date-cliente.fecha_nac_cli)/365.25>35
and credito.valor>2000
and length(tarjeta_premios.nombre)<10
and premios.fecha_premio > '2016-08-17'
;

Comment: @gbianchi no, no lo se hacer  :C osea pues, lo que se me viene a la mente es poner current_date- month '50' o algo asi pero no me funciona, me podrias ayudar ?

Comment: usa el boton [edit] y pone el codigo como texto en la pregunta...

Comment: te fijaste en la documentacion? buscaste en google?

Comment: and (current_date-premios.fecha_premio)/30<=50 al final pude hacerlo así